# Are AC circuits limited to only a serial connection?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current

What would happen if you set a condensator, a resistor and a solenoid all parallel to each other in an AC circuit? Would it not work or is there a way?

Comment: Yes, it would work. You simply have to consider the equivalent impedence of these components.

Comment: If by "condenser" you mean capacitor, you need to be aware of one thing.  For AC current, a capacitor that is not in series with a resistor acts like a short circuit.

Comment: No,  it doesn't. It's impedance is not zero,  it has a finite value for any frequency of the AC.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it would work fine, and here's how.

At low frequencies, the inductor looks like a low impedance, and shunts low frequency signals to ground. At high frequencies, the capacitor looks like a low impedance, and shunts high frequencies to ground. At inbetween frequencies, the resistor looks like an ordinary resistance and shunts a bit of all frequencies to ground.

The result is a *bandpass filter*, a circuit in common use in audio applications. The high and low cutoffs are determined by sizes of the inductor and the capacitor. The sharpness of the bandpass effect is set by the size of the resistor: the smaller it is, the less sharp the high and low frequency cutoffs are. Omitting it entirely makes the bandpass characteristic more selective and "peaked" in the midrange frequencies.